# Double-click bash file -> pwd outputs my home directory instead of the current directory

Tags: applications, bash, script

In my `Downloads` directory, I have an executable bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
```

when I double-click on it, `pwd` outputs my home directory. But I want my script to run from the current directory from where it was clicked.

Comment: Should have checked for duplicates first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts/commands are always run from your home directory (which may be inconvenient for scripts run both from Terminal *and* from Finder). To find the directory they are stored in you need to look at `$0` (which contains the full path and name of the script):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '$0:' $0
echo 'Script stored at:' ${0%/*}
cd "${0%/*}"
pwd
```